# Blender 2.8 Colour wheel weirdness

Tags: color

Using 2.8 Beta I discovered that most of my colour values end up being a shade of pink, (irritatingly) and I'm not sure quite what's going on. It happens with literally everything. Is there a setting I need to change, or is this actually a bug? As you can see in the screen recording, the white dot in the centre is moving around.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **render** tab - **color managment** set **Display device** to **sRGB**

[image]

Maybe, it is a good point for 2.8 start with factory settings.

Comment: Bit of a pain to have to do this, sRGB looks like mud.